# Play app in prod mode, how to run

Tags: playframework-2.0

I've tried the following variations:

1. `play '~run' prod`
2. `play ~run --%prod` (I know it's play 1.x but I still tried)
3. `play -Dplay.id=prod '~run'`

`application.mode=prod` inside conf/application.conf.

Can someone tell me what I missed?

EDIT: @bassebergman's answer solves my problem. wondering if anyone knows if there is a way to have prod mode and triggered compilation both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Production#Using-the-start-command), try

```
play start
```

Comment: Thanks, no way to do a triggered compilation/run yet use prod mode?

Comment: To answer the question in my comment, no. Triggered compilation is not possible in prod mode.